# Apache jmeter - 2.10 - Null point exception while running an existing script

Tags: nullpointerexception, jmeter

The Jmeter script runs fine on apache-jmeter2.8. I upgraded recently to apache-jmeter-2.10 and I started getting Null Point exception.

I revert back to apache-jmeter2.8 and the script works fine.

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jorphan.util.JOrphanUtils.replaceAllChars(JOrphanUtils.java:264)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.encodeSpaces(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.followRedirects(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1404)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1482)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:306)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:381)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The script is general login script and the failure happens when it is trying to post.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be facing this known bug that has been fixed in nightly build:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55717

As a workaround, try changing http implementation to Java instead of HttpClient4 implementation.

If you want to give nightly build a try, see:

```
http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html
```

Read:

> Installing JMeter runtime
>
> Download the _bin and _lib files
>
> Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
>
> The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.

Comment: Changed http implementation to Java and it is working fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above error has been addressed in 2.11 version. Download and use the latest version of jmeter 2.11 and check out your script.

No need to go for Nightly Build.