# jmeter null pointer exception after a few successful samples

Tags: jmeter

I have a `jmeter` test plan that logs into a site simulates some ajax requests, simulates hiting a couple of random pages and then loops.

The **problem** is that after a few succesful samples I start getting **`null property can't be cast`** exceptions:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.NullProperty cannot be cast to org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments.getArguments(Arguments.java:54)
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments.iterator(Arguments.java:145)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.getQueryString(HTTPSamplerBase.java:966)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.getUrl(HTTPSamplerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It looks very similar to the following issue that was apparently solved in 2.11

[Apache jmeter - 2.10 - Null point exception while running an existing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199383/apache-jmeter-2-10-null-point-exception-while-running-an-existing-script)

but I think it's a little bit different. **Any suggestions?** Thanks!

Comment: can you show your test plan ?

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem when i was useing:

```
${__BeanShell( if(vars.get("GroupingThreads")=="1") {return "Debug Sampler";}else {return ctx.getThreadGroup().getName()+"-"+${__threadNum()}+"-"+": Debug Sampler";})}
```

After several time works then returned errors ( also on clients machines)

then i changed to:

```
${__BeanShell( if("${GroupingThreads}"=="1") {return "Debug Sampler";}else {return ctx.getThreadGroup().getName()+"-"+${__threadNum()}+"-" + "${var_Username}"+": Debug Sampler";})}
```

Now , test are working witnh no erors